# Какие технологии выбрать для web и android приложений, которые будут работать с одной БД?

Tags: android, база-данных, веб-программирование, клиент-сервер

Выбрал для диплома следующее задание:

Создаётся БД с разными 4К изображениями. Далее создаётся веб-клиент, который позволяет работать с базой в разных ролях - редактировать записи, удалять, добавлять и т. д. Пока планируются только роли администратора и автора изображений. Также создаётся Android-приложение, которое позволяет просматривать каталог картинок, искать по имени и тегам, и самое важное - обрезает и устанавливает в качестве фона рабочего стола нужную картинку.

Вопрос в следующем: какие технологии стоит выбрать для реализации, как правильно построить архитектуру? Какую лучше взять БД? На чём писать веб-клиент?

Смотрел в сторону Firebase в качестве БД, для веба Node.js. 
Может, посоветуете что-то получше? Ранее работал только с JavaFX, немного с Android и PHP. Буду благодарен за аргументированные ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase в данном случае подойдёт идеально, потому что нагрузки не предполагается. Соответственно, будет бесплатно.

И андроид и веб будут обращаться по своим интерфейсам к БД и работать с ней.

Архитектуры как таковой в данном случае нет, так как у приложения всего пара функций которые успешно размещаются на одном рабочем экране.

Comment: Хорошо, а как насчёт того, на чём писать веб-клиент? Подойдёт для этих целей node.js?

Comment: Насколько я понял из задачи, "веб клиент" это что то типа веб-страницы в интернете, к которой тоже прикручены несколько кнопочек и две роли. Думаю, нет смысла подключать вообще что-либо, кроме PHP.

Comment: Суть диплома ещё и в том, что система должна быть расширяемой, без переписывания половины кода. Например, если в будущем нужно будет добавить какую-либо функцию (добавить роль, редактирование фото с помощью фильтров и т. д.), чтобы это можно было сделать, лишь дописав нужный код, а не переписав всё с нуля. Мне кажется, на чистом PHP такое писать бессмысленно.

Пример того, как я хочу чтобы выглядело веб-приложение - сайт wallscloud, только я хочу добавить возможность редактирования базы администратором и пользователем (с ограниченными правами). Пример Android приложения - wallpaperscraft.

Comment: Не вижу связи между будущим расширением и выбором языков и фреймворков. Любое приложение можно расширить. Если уж на то пошло, что вы считаете, что вам нужен полноценный фронтенд, то смотрите в сторону LARAVEL https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laravel.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за советы, буду разбираться ☺